# Enabling Edition Based Redefinition failed with ora-33819. Could I query why?

Tags: oracle

I want to enable Edition Based Redefinition for a user. Executing this command gives an ORA-33819 exception:

```
ALTER USER user ENABLE EDITIONS;
```

I know there's an option to enable it with the parameter Force

```
ALTER USER user ENABLE EDITIONS FORCE;
```

but as this operation is retroactive and irreversible, I would rather see beforehand why it failed. Does anyone know how to get a list of problems before altering the user?

Working on an Oracle 12.1.0.1.0

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698252/enabling-edition-based-redefinition-failed-with-ora-33819-could-i-query-why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First you need to be sure that there are no more evolved ADT (Abstract Data Types):

```
select t.*
from DBA_TYPE_VERSIONS t
where Owner = 'USER'
  and t.version# > 1;
```

You have to reset all this types before you can enable Edition Based Redefinition for a user.

```
 ALTER TYPE *TYPE_NAME* RESET;
```

Restriction on RESET: You cannot specify RESET if the type has any table dependents (direct or indirect)

Link: [ALTER TYPE Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/alter_type.htm)

2) If you have tables which are based on XML Schema's you'll have to move the definition to another schema and recreate the table based on that definition. It's a bit strange though, I had expecting that those types would be generated "NONEDITIONABLE" by default?

```
 select *
 from USER_XML_SCHEMAS;
```

Link: [XML Schema Storage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17603/xdb05sto.htm#i1042421)

3) If you are using Advanced Queueing, drop your queue's, and types and recreate the types with the NONEDITIONABLE property:

```
select * --> Look for "Object_Type" = Type_Name
from User_Queue_Tables;

drop queue ...;
drop type *TYPE_NAME*;

create NONEDITIONABLE type *TYPE_NAME* as ...;
create queue ...;
```

So, that did it for me

Answer (score 0):

You can query something like this:

```
select o.owner, o.object_name, o.object_type, edition_name, editionable from dba_dependencies d, dba_objects o 
where o.owner = d.referenced_owner
and o.object_name = d.referenced_name
and d.owner = 'USER'
and o.editionable = 'Y'
and o.edition_name is NULL;
```

This is will list the objects referenced by user 'USER', that are editionable but dont have any editions - thus preventing you from enabling EBR for 'USER'.

Comment: That didn't work. With your view I have a list of all the objects that are editionable, but not the ones that will give problems. As a test, I created a user, and then a table and package for that user. When executing your query I had a list of 2 objects. But enabling EBR for this user worked like a charm.